# How can I manage a notification push system

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have to manage a set of notify as it is showed in this image (Never mind of the duplicates):

[image: notifications]

I have to send a notification for every item, managing when the notification is removed (so the app haven't to send the notify) and also when the "notify" is changed (date and time).
How can I manage all this, also when the app is in background/sleeping?

**This is my method in CoreActivity.java:**

```
public void notifyPush(Date datetime)
    {
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(context,NotificationReceiver.class);
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        //nuovo codice
        Intent intent = new Intent(CoreActivity.this , NotificationReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(CoreActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours



        //fine nuovo codice
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Notifica")
                .setContentText("Abbiamo le notifiche").
                        addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Open", pendingIntent)
                .addAction(0, "Remind", pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

**NotificationReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.msnma.movienotifier.notify;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.R;

public class NotificationReceiver extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_core);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Notification Text");

        setContentView(tv);
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at Android WorkManager Library and examples